# Getting more details out of a SQL subquery

Tags: sql, subquery

I have a SQL Query giving me a list of double records in my database.

```
select periodid, itemid from periodscore  
group by periodid, itemid
having count(*) > 1
```

This works as expected, but now I would like to retrieve additional fields of these records (such as date last updated etc).  So I tried:

```
select * from periodscore where periodscoreid in
(select periodscoreid from periodscore  
group by periodid, itemid
having count(*) > 1)
```

Of course this doesn't work and gives me the error:

> Column 'periodscore.PeriodScoreID' is
>   invalid in the select list because it
>   is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

How can I retrieve the extra fields in this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select ps.* 
from periodscore ps
inner join (
    select periodid, itemid 
    from periodscore   
    group by periodid, itemid 
    having count(*) > 1
) psm on ps.periodid = psm.periodid and ps.itemid = psm.itemid
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! This query as well gives me 216 records as opposed to the original 103

Comment: @Sam - The first query tells you the groups. This gives you the rows belonging to those groups. Of course all of the groups will have at least 2 rows as that is the purpose of the query! If you only want one row per group returned then which one?

Comment: @Martin, Some rows duplicated more than two times, for getting exactly 206 rows should be used condition count(*) = 2

Answer (score 1):

```
  select p1.* from periodscore p1 JOIN 
  (select periodid, itemid from periodscore  
   group by periodid, itemid
   having count(*) > 1) p2
   ON (p1.periodId = p2.periodId
       AND p1.itemid = p2.itemid)
```

if periodid or item have null values then

```
  select p1.* from periodscore p1 JOIN 
  (select periodid, itemid from periodscore  
   group by periodid, itemid
   having count(*) > 1) p2
   ON (IFNULL(p1.periodId,0) = IFNULL(p2.periodId,0))
       AND IFNULL(p1.itemid,0) = IFNULL(p2.itemid,0))
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! However, this query seems to give me about the double number of records I get from the original one... Original one gave me 103 records, this one 216...

Comment: @Same, Added IFNULL for cases when periodid or itemid is null

Comment: I'm guessing you meant ISNULL? The ids are actually uniqueidentifiers, but you had no way of knowing that.

Comment: @Sam, You had rows which duplicated more than 2 times :)